# how to divide these values using pivot or groupby table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

have a list of ranks from 1-100 divided among 1000 people for multiple exams

Snippet:

```
name     rank  
mark     1
stuart   2
lee      15
lenord   8
sheldon  99
cubbon   26
stuart   35
lee      40
lenord   66
mark     9
sheldon  1
cubbon   2
mark     100
mark     6
```

using pivot and groupby how to divide this something like this based on count

```
name        0-9   10-19 20-29  30-39 40-49 50-59 60-69 70-79 80-89 90-100

mark         3       0    0      0     0     0     0     0    0      1
stuart       1       0    0      1     0     0     0     0    0      0   
lee          0       1    0      0     1     0     0     0    0      0   
lenord       1       0    0      0     0     0     1     0    0      0  
sheldon      1       0    0      0     0     0     0     0    0      1 
cubbon       1       0    1      0     0     0     0     0    0      0
```

tried pivot and groupby , but how to create the columns 0-10 .....  90-100 automatically rather than manually

Tried this : but it is taking long time

```
rank_1_10=df[(df['rank'] >= 0) & (df['rank'] <= 10)]

rank_1_10=rank_1_10.groupby(['name']).agg({'rank': 'count'})

......

rank_100=df[(df['rank'] >= 90) & (df['rank'] <= 100)]

rank_10=rank_100.groupby(['name']).agg({'rank': 'count'})
```

Then i'm merging all these, is there any easy way

Comment: @jezrael tried following the post but could'nt figure out

Comment: What so you try?

Comment: post data has binned values , but mine is divide these into separate columns. just started learning on groupby , aggregation , pivot .

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745831/after-binning-a-column-of-a-dataframe-how-to-make-a-new-dataframe-to-count-the

Comment: @Pygirl - No, because no labels, not reindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) by `np.arange` and labels created by `zip`, last value is different, so is corrected adding by `1` in bins and subtracted `1` in labels:

```
bins = np.arange(0, 110, 10)
#dynamically create labels
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i, j-1) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
bins[-1] += 1
labels[-1] = '{}-{}'.format(bins[-2], bins[-1]-1)

df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['rank'], bins = bins, labels=labels, right=False)
print (df)
       name  rank  binned
0      mark     1     0-9
1    stuart     2     0-9
2       lee    15   10-19
3    lenord     8     0-9
4   sheldon    99  90-100
5    cubbon    26   20-29
6    stuart    35   30-39
7       lee    40   40-49
8    lenord    66   60-69
9      mark     9     0-9
10  sheldon     1     0-9
11   cubbon     2     0-9
12     mark   100  90-100
13     mark     6     0-9
```

Then for count is used [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add all not exist columns:

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['binned']).reindex(labels, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
binned   0-9  10-19  20-29  30-39  40-49  50-59  60-69  70-79  80-89  90-100
name                                                                        
cubbon     1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0       0
lee        0      1      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0
lenord     1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0       0
mark       3      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       1
sheldon    1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       1
stuart     1      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0       0
```